# Grails Unit Test Controller with JSON Request

Tags: json, testing, grails, parameters, controller

i have this stuff in a controller:

```
def show{
render (contentType: "text/json"){
        needid = stuff.id
        owner = stuff.owner.username
        title = stuff.title
}
```

as I use my Browser, "stuff/show/3"  will show me stuff with the id 3

Now my question:

How do I write a unit test controller, more precisely, how do I send the parameter "3" ?

My suggestion:

```
void testShow(){
            request.json = ???? //how to send id parameter?

            controller.show()

            println(response.text); // show me whats the response

            assert '3' == response.text  //assert something, not sure if correct
}
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Why and how do you think the service takes JSON request?

Comment: I read some doc files about unit testing on controllers and this is all I could think of. Could you help me ?

Comment: Start from [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/).

Answer (score 0):

1.Have you added the @TestFor annotation?

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(SimpleController)
class SimpleControllerTests {
    void testSomething() {

    }
}
```

2.If you haven't do any special configuration, I guess that the params for request is NOT json. So you can simply do:

```
params.id = 3
```

For more details, you can refer to the Grails 2.0 Document about Controller Unit test [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers) (**Strongly recommended**).